# Oracle ODI JDBC driver for SQL Server 2005 connection error

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2005, jdbc

I am using Oracle ODI 11.1.1.7 version on a Windows 7 64bit machine. I want to connect to a SQL Server 2005 database using the driver `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`.

I have downloaded and installed from Microsoft the drivers

- Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.1 for SQL Server

and also

- Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server

But I still have a connection error:

> ODI-26039: Connection failed
>
> Java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]

Did anyone else experience this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check this url. You need the specific driver depending upon the version of JDBC. You need to elaborate more on your question.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378422(v=sql.110).aspx